# changing css after the page is rendered to cater RTL or LTR text

Tags: css

Mine is a single page js website which gets text from a web request in json format. The text format (RTL or LTR) will only be known when the response is received. Is there a way we can re render the page once response is received? ie.., once the response is recieved either change the css files or set the html tag for dir and get the styles to be re applied?

Answer (score 0):

You could always do something like

```
document.getElementById('div id here').style.color='red'
```

Or you could do soemthing like

```
$("div id here").css("color","red");
```

Just an example but once the response is recieved, you could add that there so it changes the style of the div.